# Is it much easier to make entire human population to have blood type O than type AB?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, science-in-society, blood, medical

Not all human blood are equal thanks to the antigens that prefer to strap themselves onto surfaces of cells. They are like a signal flare to inform soldiers whether target is friendly or not, most of the time the intelligence is accurate. I want only a specific blood type for humanity and I'm confused between type O and type AB, which is preferred medically? How to go about it with minimum casualty and within a decade time? Answer with the least casualties, lowest budget and shortest time frame wins(you may throw ethics out the window).

Comment: Asking how to make the entire human population have only one blood type in the shortest time with the least deaths and lowest budget ... is **very broad**. Answers will be incredibly long to cover all these bases, and no two people will have the same idea for how to do it! Consider narrowing the question.

Comment: And don't forget that you also must make everybody [Rh negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rh_blood_group_system), or at least have everybody manifest the same Rh factors.

Answer (score 7):

A population of type AB is not stable.  Given a uniform population of type AB, the next generation will be 25% type-A, 25% type-B, 50% AB.

A population containing only type-O will be stable as each generation will continue to be type-O.

Comment: More precisely, IMO, 25% A-A, 25% B-B...

Comment: If the whole populace went to B only or A only, would that be stable? Or would you still get some Os?

Comment: @SRM Depends. If you would make everyone generically A-A,  it would be stable. If you will have some A-0, it wouldn't.

Comment: @SRM You should read up on Phenotype vs Genotype.

Comment: @SRM If you started out with 100% AB, and then culled the population to get only A or B, then anyone with type-A would be AA and anyone with type-B would be BB.  Starting with a full population of AB, A, B, O, it would take genetic testing to determine whether type-A is AA or AO.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable word level government
2. Forbid reproduction to those who do not have 0 blood type.
3. Wait until the reaper does it job.

Btw, the only reason why 0 is preferred is because it is more compatible with other types: 0 Rh - has no "labels", to raise alarms, so anybody can accept it.
AB Rh + instead has so many "labels" (A, B and +) that can be accepted only by those having all the 3 of them.